# IE9 Layout Bug - fine in earlier IE versions

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

Here is my site:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/pp/

The very bottom menu is laid out correctly in every browser ive tested, including IE8 and IE7. However with IE9 its starts further to the right than it should and the twitter icon is pushed down to the next line. How can I fix this?

I tried to install firebug lite to see whats going on but I cant extract the firebug-lite.tar.tgz file. 
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one of the relatively positioned divs needed to be given a set width.